# Problem in PyCharm with import function/class from standard module

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-poetry

I am coding in PyCharm and to set up the environment I use poetry, python version 3.10

Everything was working ok, but starting from one moment of time I got problem with module imports.
But the problem does not relate to the import of the whole module but to the import of class or function from module.
You can see as an example that BaseSettings from pydantic is underlined with red wavy line and Pycharm says that BaseSettings is unresolved reference.

I tried

1. to invalidate cache in Pycharm
2. install, uninstall the module (poetry add/remove)
3. change the environment and return back
4. marked folder as a source root (assume it is irrelevant but anyway)

but unfortunately nothing helped

[image]
[image]

**aiohttp.client.py**
[image: aiohttp.client.py]

**aiohttp.**init**.py**
[image: aiohttp.init.py]

Comment: How are those classes defined in the modules they're being imported from? Are they defined conditionally/dynamically?

Comment: probably I do not clearly got your question, but these are standart modules were installed using `poetry add pydantic`, I believe that under the hood it uses. `pip install ...`. Since IDE does not provide the link to these functions/classed (the reference is unresolved for IDE), I can not check how they are defined.

Comment: Navigate to the source of `aiohttp` (`CTRL+LEFT-MOUSE` in PyCharm), and see where/how `ClientSession` is defined. If it's being defined in an unusual manner (like inside an `if` block, or as the result of some computation) PyCharm's completion engine may not be able to analyze it properly

Comment: If I click on the aiohttp with cmd keyboard it goes to __init__.py. However, if I try to do the same with ClientSession it does not work and shows hint 'Cannot find declaration to go to'

Comment: I added screens to the problem description

Answer (score 0):

I found the out what was the reason for this strange behaviour. It was the problem of PyCharm IDE. PyCharm stopped recognising **init**.py as python files that produced import errors. Actually I do not know why this happened since I did not changed any settings or updated PyCharm.

The solution was to manually add pattern "**init**.py" to python files mask in Settings -> Editor ->File types -> Python (please see screenshot in the attachment)

[image]